# Form submission via JS does not pass through jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form in 'index.php`

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myInput" id="myInput" maxlength="9" onChange="runOnce();" />
</form>
```

and in my JS code I have:

```
function runOnce() {
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    form.submit();
}
```

and I also have the JS to handle the submission

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
         // prevent page refresh
         event.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
             url: 'index.php',
             type: 'post',
             data: {
                 "myInput" : $('#myInput').val(), 
             },
             success: function(response) {
                 alert(response);
             }
         });
    });
});
```

and in my PHP section I have

```
if (isset($_POST["myInput"])) {
    // do something. . . 
}
```

The issue is that the page is still being refreshed even though i have `event.preventDefault();`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `form.submit()` won't trigger jQuery handler, `$(form).submit();` will

Comment: the event passed is for inputcontrol and not submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use:

```
function runOnce() {
    $("#myForm").submit(); // this will trigger jQuery submit handler and so preventing default behaviour
}
```

Comment: how is that any different from what I am doing now?

Comment: Read duplicated link, your code wasn't triggering jQuery submit handler, this one will

Comment: I just tried it and it still refreshes the page and has similar behaviour

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/3eCFB/

Comment: it works in th ejsfiddle, but not on my page. the jsfiddle does not have the `if (isset($_POST["myInput"]))` PHP portion. can that be the reason?

Comment: You have to debug it on your side, nothing i can do here. But anyway, the server side code will be called after the default behaviour being applied to the FORM submit, so no, your issue seems to be somewhere else. Maybe you are not binding the submit event, etc...

Comment: You were 100% right. I had to delete cache and history and refresh the page in order to force it work! The code works! Thanks